# django paginator - how to show all page numbers available

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have simple issue:

I have this `{{ objects.paginator.num_pages }}` in template, which gives me the total number of pages that contain items.

now i want to show those page numbers like this

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

to achieve this, i need to make forloop till `the num_pages`. like `for i to num_pages`.

how is it possible in django template? i am reading some snippets, but they are a bit difficult to understand for me.

Comment: See https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`page_range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.page_range)

```
{% for page in objects.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if forloop.counter != 1 %} | {% endif %}
    {{ page }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yeah, thanks now i see this in the docs. sorry for dumb question

Answer (score 22):

Formatted with twitter bootstrap and with links:

```
 <ul class="pagination nav navbar-nav">
    {% if objects.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ objects.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page in objects.paginator.page_range %}
        <li class="{% if objects.number == page  %}active{% endif %}"><a href="?page={{page }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if objects.has_next %}
        <li> <a href="?page={{ objects.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
    {% endif %}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the "active" implementation

Comment: This is great! I'd even add `{% if objects.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}` around the `{% for page in objects.paginator.page_range %}` so it doesn't look weird when there's only one page.